# Laurent series of $\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{(\mathrm{e}^x-1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Is their an easier way to determine the Laurent series $$\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{(\mathrm{e}^x-1)^2}$$ than expanding the numerator and the denominator?

Comment: We can notice that the function has a pole at 0. We can find the expansion in a region around 0 using the theorem [here](https://complex-analysis.com/content/laurent_series.html). This will give you the coefficients as complex integrals. The latter would be solved with the Cauchy formula. You can try this approach if you want and edit the question if still need help.

Comment: Using the decomposition $\displaystyle \frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k}{k!}x^k$ (where $B_k$ denote Bernoulli numbers)
$$\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{(\mathrm{e}^x-1)^2}=-\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\frac{1}{x}\frac{x}{e^x-1}\Big)=-\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k}{k!}x^{k-1}\Big)$$